# Need to add values to javascript array dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a php function returning an array of map coordinates.

I am then trying to place them on a google map using

```
    for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
        var via = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);
    };
```

where via is lat and longs, and coords[i][1], coords[i][2] are pulled from a php array.

This method only writes the last value of the array onto the map when the function runs, i need it to produce the entire array.

Secondly i need to pull only the last value of the array and drop it into the variable "end"
when the array is done its loop.

**** also have tried

```
  var via = [];
    for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
        via.push([new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][1], coords[i][2])]);
    };
```

and

```
   var via = [];
    for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
        var viaPoints = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);
        via.push([viaPoints]);
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop as written overwrites `via` each time, so you end up with the last value.  Instead try adding the marker to the map *inside the loop*.  (For the second part of your question, just set `end=via` after the loop is done.)

```
for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
    var via = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);

    // add marker to the map here, eg ....
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(via));
};

var end = via;
```

(In case you're not aware, the [Maps API site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/) has some helpful [examples](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/marker-simple).)

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually trying to make a route appear on a map with preexisting markers, just need to "print" array of the coordinates into another function. So via would print "56.112345, -8.999889", "8.9999787, 7.99765568", etc...... into text essentially. And then need the end point to be the last lat and long